# Swift tuple pattern matching fail to compile only for switch statement

Tags: swift, tuples, switch-statement

I have the following struct:

```swift
struct Pair<First, Second> {
    var first: First
    var second: Second

    static func ~= (pattern: (First, Second), value: Pair) -> Bool { /* code */ }
}
```

Now, the test code:

```swift
func test() {
    let tuple = (0, "zero")
    let pair = Pair(0, "zero")
    
    (0, "zero") ~= pair
    tuple ~= pair
    
    switch pair {
    case tuple: return
    case (0, "zero"): return // only this raises an error
    // error: tuple pattern cannot match values of the non-tuple type 'Pair<Int, String>'
    default: return
    }
}
```

**Question**: It doesn't seem like it's an issue with matching a tuple literal vs. a tuple instance, since a non-`switch` version is working fine.

I'm wondering if this is some bug, or there is something I need to know about `switch` statements.

Comment: Compare https://stackoverflow.com/q/46700045/1187415 or https://stackoverflow.com/q/29677991/1187415.

Comment: I've put the actual error message in as a comment. Hope you don't mind. The issue itself looks like some sort of edge case bug.

Comment: @JeremyP Not at all. It's helps people know what error is shown. Thank you

Comment: @MartinR I did check out those answers. They only prescribe workarounds, which is readily available in my case, but I would like to know what the cause is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
case tuple: return
```

This is an ["expression pattern."](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/ReferenceManual/Patterns.html#ID426) It can employ the `~=` operator:

> The expression represented by the expression pattern is compared with the value of an input expression using the Swift standard library `~=` operator.

```
case (0, "zero"): return // only this raises an error
```

This is a ["tuple pattern."](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/ReferenceManual/Patterns.html#ID423) It has different features and does not support `~=`. For example, it supports `let` bindings to individual elements of the pattern. In this example, `0` and `"zero"` are nested expression patterns, and so there could be a custom `~=` implementations for String or Int patterns that would be applied. But that won't work for a tuple, since it's interpreted as a tuple pattern.

I don't believe there's any way to create a tuple-literal expression pattern. Tuple patterns can only match tuples (which is what the error is saying: "tuple pattern cannot match values of the non-tuple type"). If this is an important feature for you, you should probably discuss on the [forums](https://forums.swift.org/).

The way to implement what you're building is to make `Pair` Equatable when its elements are Equatable, and then switch on:

```
case Pair(0, "zero"): return
```

Comment: Yeah. The code I posted is an abbreviated version. The actual implementation has members like `toTuple()` and many convenience methods. Part of the reason I'm using `Pair` is because tuples don't allow synthesized implementations--of `Equatable` for example--when used as members of otherwise `Equatable` types. So I *could* explicitly use `Pair`s in switch statements, but if it could be helped, I'd rather not.

Comment: I don't believe there's any way to do what you're asking. Swift syntax doesn't allow it. If it's a feature you'd like to pitch, I'd discuss on the forums, though I expect that it would be a major change to how `switch` statements work. Swift is not particularly fond of tuples; it favors more explicit types that name their meaning (`CGPoint` rather than `(CGFloat, CGFloat)`).  Replacing tuple with a generic "Pair" struct doesn't make Swift like this approach any more. It is a nominally typed language, not a structurally typed language.

Comment: In the early days of Swift, tuples were slightly more powerful. They were intentionally made less powerful over time to make other features cleaner. You'll also notice the lack of types like `Either` or ADTs generally. The preference is to explicitly name types. (Not everyone agrees it should be the preference, but it's definitely how the language has developed.)

Answer (score -2):

You are trying to compare a struct with a Tuple. Swift knows will never be the same, therefore it does not allow this comparison. You get the same error if you try to switch on a String and place an Int in the `case` statement (the error is a little different because Swift does special things for Tuples).